# If startyear and endyear is same than add a year after end year and store in database

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript

I am creating an array(years_array to now - 55) i want toadd a year after end year if startyear == endyear and store it in database. Let say if 2021 is selected in both the dropdown then leaving year should automatically get saved as 2022 in mysql database.years_array is a array which has value From [1967 - 2021]. I am new to Angular. Can anyone hep me out here. Thanks in advance.

```
 <nb-select placeholder="Select Academic Year" 
            (ngModelChange)="getSelectedYear()" 
                id="leavingYear" name="leavingYear" 
          formControlName="TCyearLeavingCtrl"  [ngClass]=" 
                {'form-control-danger': 
          firstForm.controls['TCyearLeavingCtrl'].invalid && 
          (firstForm.controls['TCyearLeavingCtrl'].dirty || 
          firstForm.controls['TCyearLeavingCtrl'].touched)}">
          <nb-option value="{{years}}" *ngFor="let years of years_array">
                             {{years}}
                           </nb-option>
                         </nb-select>
```

```
 <nb-select placeholder="Select Academic Year" 
      (ngModelChange)="getSelectedYear()" id="leavingYear" 
    name="leavingYear" formControlName="TCyearLeavingCtrl" 
     [ngClass]="{'form-control- 
       danger':firstForm.controls['TCyearLeavingCtrl'].invalid && 
         (firstForm.controls['TCyearLeavingCtrl'].dirty || 
          firstForm.controls['TCyearLeavingCtrl'].touched)}">
        <nb-option value="{{years}}" *ngFor="let years of 
             years_array"> {{years}}
                    </nb-option>
                  </nb-select>
```

```
  

getSelectedYear() {
  this.tranReqYear = [];
  var d = new Date();
  const now = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
  this.years_array = Array(now - (now - 55))
                        .fill("")
                        .map((v, idx) => now - idx);
  if (this.firstForm.controls.TCyearEnrollmentCtrl.value 
    && this.firstForm.controls.TCyearLeavingCtrl.value) 
  {
    this.startYear = 
    this.firstForm.controls.TCyearEnrollmentCtrl.value;
    this.startYear = Number(this.startYear);
    this.endYear = this.firstForm.controls.TCyearLeavingCtrl.value;
    this.endYear = Number(this.endYear);
  }
   for (let info of this.years_array) {
    console.log("i=======" + info);
    if (this.startYear == this.endYear) {
        this.endYear=this.endYear+1;
        console.log('End Year',this.endYear);
        this.tranReqYear.push(info);
      } else if(info >= this.startYear && info <= this.endYear){
        console.log("$$$$$$");
        this.tranReqYear.push(info);

        console.log("startyear",this.startYear);
        console.log("endyear",this.endYear);
        console.log("Check TranReqYear" + this.tranReqYear);
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: ___I want to alter the given function so that .....___ No I think you want someone here to alter the code. We are not a code writing service. _You have a go, and if it does not work, you come back and ask a question based on a concreet coding problem._

Comment: And why do you undo the code formatting back to poorly formatted code

Comment: You are taking it wrong. I tried adding else if condition if startyear and end year is same than +1 end year and push in database it won't work for me @RiggsFolly

Comment: So show us the code you have tried, if nothing else it will help us understand this code

Comment: I have updated my ques. @RiggsFolly